# Error in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, button

I am trying to create a button which will give random values for certain parameters. I am using the following in `Manipulate[]`.

```
Delimiter, Button["Arbitary Parameters", time = 0;
 r = RandomReal[{0.04, 0.3}];
 c = RandomReal[{0, 0.15}];
 μ = RandomReal[{0, 0.25}]],
{{tMax, 30}, ControlType -> None},
TrackedSymbols :> True, ControlPlacement -> Left,
```

However, I get the following errors:

> "Manipulate argument TrackedSymbols:>True does not have the correct \
>   form for a variable specification." "Manipulate argument
>   ControlPlacement->Left does not have the correct \ form for a variable
>   specification. "

How do I resolve this so that I can create a button which when used will randomly change the values of the parameters?

Code including manipulate wrapper:

```
Manipulate[If[time > tMax, time = tMax];
 Quiet @ 
   Module[{g = 9.8, R = 1, m, center, axis1, axis2, eqn, sol},
   m = 2.52*(4/3)*π*r^3;
   eqn = {ϕ''[t] == (
       5*(r - R)*Sin[2*θ[t]]*θ'[t]*ϕ'[t])/(
       2*r^2 - 5*r*Sin[θ[t]]^2 + 5*R*Sin[θ[t]]^2) - 
       c*ϕ'[t]*(R - r)*
        Sqrt[θ'[t]^2 + 
          Sin[θ[t]]^2*ϕ'[t]^2] - μ*7/5*r/
        g*ϕ'[t]*(R - r)*
        Sqrt[θ'[t]^2 + Sin[θ[t]]^2*ϕ'[t]^2],
     θ''[t] == -g*Sin[θ[t]] + 
       Cos[θ[t]]*Sin[θ[t]]*ϕ'[t]^2 - 
       c*θ'[t]*(R - r)*
        Sqrt[θ'[t]^2 + 
          Sin[θ[t]]^2*ϕ'[t]^2] - μ*7/5*r/
        g*θ'[t]*(R - r)*
        Sqrt[θ'[t]^2 + Sin[θ[t]]^2*ϕ'[t]^2],
     r ψ[t] == -(R - r)*θ[t], 
     r α[t] == -(R - r)*ϕ[t],
     θ[0] == θ0, θ'[0] == θd0, ϕ[
       0] == ϕ0, ϕ'[0] == ϕd0};
   sol = First[
     NDSolve[eqn, {ϕ, θ, ψ, α}, {t, 0, time}]];
   center[t_, 
     r_] = (R - r)*{Sin[θ[t]]*Cos[ϕ[t]], 
       Sin[θ[t]]*Sin[ϕ[t]], -Cos[θ[t]]} /. sol;
   axis1[t_] = {Sin[ϕ[time]], -Cos[ϕ[time]], 0} /. sol;
   axis2[t_] = {Cos[θ[time]]*Cos[ϕ[time]], 
      Cos[θ[time]]*Sin[ϕ[time]], Sin[θ[time]]} /. 
     sol;
   Graphics3D[{bowl,
     If[tr, 
      ParametricPlot3D[center[t, 0], {t, 0, time}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
        PlotStyle -> Directive[{Thick, Blue}]][[1]], {}],
     {Specularity[1, 25],
      Rotate[
       Rotate[marble[center[time, r], r],
        (α[time]) /. sol, axis2[time], center[time, r]],
       ψ[time] /. sol, axis1[time], center[time, r]]}},
    Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
    PlotRange -> {All, All, {-R, 2}}, ViewAngle -> 40 °, 
    ViewPoint -> {1, 0, 2.7}, ImageSize -> {400, 400}]],
 Style["Animation", Bold], {{time, 0.001, ""}, 0.001, tMax, .15, 
  Trigger, AnimationRate -> 1, 
  AppearanceElements -> {"PlayButton", "PauseButton", 
    "StepLeftButton", "StepRightButton", "ResetButton"}, 
  ImageSize -> Large}, Delimiter,
 Style["Parameters", Bold],
 "\nRadius of the Marble", {{r, .1, "r"}, 0.04, 0.3, .01, 
  ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 "Drag on the Marble", {{c, .09, "c"}, 0, .15, .01, ImageSize -> Tiny,
   Appearance -> 
   "Labeled"}, "Friction between the ball and the surface", {{μ, \
.07, "μ"}, 0, .25, .01, ImageSize -> Tiny, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, Delimiter,
 Style["Initial Conditions", Bold],
 "\nAngular Position", "  \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(θ\), \(0\)]\)=\
π/2", {{ϕ0, -2.7, 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(0\)]\)"}, -3.14, 3.14, .01, 
  ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 "\nAngular Speed", "  θ\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\('\), \(0\)]\)=0", \
{{ϕd0, .90, "ϕ\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\('\), \(0\)]\)"}, -2, 
  2, .01, ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, Delimiter,
 {{θ0, π/2}, ControlType -> None}, {{θd0, 0}, 
  ControlType -> None},


 Delimiter, Evaluate[Button["Arbitary Parameters", time = 0;
   r = RandomReal[{0.04, 0.3}];
   c = RandomReal[{0, 0.15}];
   μ = RandomReal[{0, 0.25}]]],
 {{tMax, 30}, ControlType -> None},
 TrackedSymbols :> True, ControlPlacement -> Left,

 Row[{"Path Followed", Control[{{tr, True, ""}, {True, False}}]}],
 {{tMax, 30}, ControlType -> None},
 TrackedSymbols -> Manipulate, ControlPlacement -> Left,

 (*Delimiter,Button["Arbitary Parameters",time=0;
 r=RandomInteger[{0.04,0.3}];
 c=RandomInteger[{0,0.15}];
 μ=RandomInteger[{0,0.25}]],
 {{tMax,30},ControlType\[Rule]None},
 TrackedSymbols\[RuleDelayed]True, ControlPlacement\[Rule]Left,*)


 Initialization :> (bowl = 
    RegionPlot3D[
      1 < x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1.25, {x, -1.25, 1.25}, {y, -1.25, 
       1.25}, {z, -1.25, 0}, PlotPoints -> 32, 
      BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], Boxed -> False, 
      Axes -> False, Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .5}, 
      TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2, #3} &)][[1]];
   marble[{x_, y_, z_}, 
     r_] := {{Black, Sphere[{x, y, z}, r]}, {Black, 
      Sphere[{x, y, z + 0.025}, .999 r]}})]
```

Comment: "Error in Manipulate" is a vast understatement. There are so many errors that I am unable to quantify them. My first piece of advice is that you should read the documentation concerning `TrackedSymbols`. Your use of it is both syntactically and semantically wrong.

Comment: I think your differential equations are not correct. Try to solve them separately, outside the `Manipulate` first. Since you have four variables, I think you should have four equations and eight initial conditions. Once you successfully solve the DE outside, write a module which takes in time and initial conditions and returns the output of the `NDSolve`. Modularising the code helps is debugging.

Comment: @Saurav:  It is only the Button named as 'Arbitary Parameters' that is giving the error. Rest all seem to work fine and I am not quite sure how to resolve this particular error.

Comment: @m_goldberg: Apologies for the inconvenience. I am relatively new to Mathematica and did follow the syntax as given in the Wolfram Documentation Help. I tried using TrackedSymbols:> {r,c,\[Mu]} as well but it returns the same error.

Comment: For a start, don't use `TrackedSymbols` at all

Comment: @m_goldberg:  It gives the same error for Control Placement as well. But for other rows, there is no such error. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think `ControlPlacement `and `ControlType-> None` can go together. Reduce the complexity of your code and then keep adding features. It's difficult to debug when several aspects of the code are returning errors!

Comment: Options must appear after all the controls specifications are given. Move `ControlPlacement` to the end of the Manipulate expression.

Comment: @Saurav: If you check for the Row named as 'Path Followed'  both Control Placement and Control Type-> work fine. Error is given only for the button named as 'Arbitary Parameters'.  Thanks

Comment: @m_goldberg: Apologies, but I didn't quite get what you have suggested. Thanks

Comment: How can you get a `RandomInteger` between `0.04, 0.3`?

Comment: Use `RandomReal`

Comment: @Saurav; Yes, I changed RandomInteger to RandomReal, but I get the same error. Thanks

Comment: What is the error now? Are you talking about the `TrackedSymbols`, just get rid of those, at least for now. Try to solve one problem at a time.

Comment: @Saurav: Resolved. Placed only one Track Symbol and Control Placement at the end of the expressions. Thanks

Comment: You should be getting `Times is not a Graphic3D object` error and the figure must be shaded red. Is it? If not you are done!

Comment: @Saurav: Runs perfectly now. Thanks.   Though is it possible to revolve or rotate the 3D bowl about a particular axis, at the same time the small sphere is rolling inside it? Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to say "Thanks" here! It's understood. You can always upvote and accept answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer. It is a long, long way from being an answer. It is a comment that needs to show a lot of code and an image.

Here is your code after some clean up. It doesn't work, but at least it makes an initial display close to what you likely want. I hope it will help you to work further on your problem.

```
Manipulate[
  If[time > tMax, time = tMax];
  Module[{g = 9.8, R = 1, m, center, axis1, axis2, eqn, sol}, 
   m = 2.52*(4/3)*π*r^3;
   eqn = 
     {ϕ''[t] == (5*(r - R)*Sin[2*θ[t]]*θ'[t]*ϕ'[t])/(2*r^2 - 
        5*r*Sin[θ[t]]^2 + 5*R*Sin[θ[t]]^2) - c*ϕ'[t]*(R - r)*Sqrt[θ'[t]^2 + 
        Sin[θ[t]]^2*ϕ'[t]^2] - μ*7/5*r/g*ϕ'[t]*(R - r)*Sqrt[θ'[t]^2 + 
        Sin[θ[t]]^2*ϕ'[t]^2], 
      θ''[t] == -g*Sin[θ[t]] + Cos[θ[t]]*Sin[θ[t]]*ϕ'[t]^2 - 
        c*θ'[t]*(R - r)*Sqrt[θ'[t]^2 + Sin[θ[t]]^2*ϕ'[t]^2] - 
        μ*7/5*r/g*θ'[t]*(R - r)*Sqrt[θ'[t]^2 + Sin[θ[t]]^2*ϕ'[t]^2], 
      r ψ[t] == -(R - r)*θ[t], 
      r α[t] == -(R - r)*ϕ[t], 
      θ[0] == θ0, θ'[0] == θd0, ϕ[0] == ϕ0, ϕ'[0] == ϕd0};
   sol = 
     First[NDSolve[eqn, {ϕ, θ, ψ, α}, {t, 0, time}]];
   center[t_, r_] = 
     (R - r)*{Sin[θ[t]]*Cos[ϕ[t]], Sin[θ[t]]*Sin[ϕ[t]], -Cos[θ[t]]} /. sol;
   axis1[t_] = {Sin[ϕ[time]], -Cos[ϕ[time]], 0} /. sol;
   axis2[t_] = 
     {Cos[θ[time]]*Cos[ϕ[time]], Cos[θ[time]]*Sin[ϕ[time]], Sin[θ[time]]} /. sol;
   Graphics3D[{
     bowl, 
     If[tr, 
       ParametricPlot3D[center[t, 0], {t, 0, time}, 
         PlotPoints -> 50, 
         PlotStyle -> Directive[{Thick, Blue}]][[1]], {}], 
     {Specularity[1, 25], 
      Rotate[
        Rotate[marble[center[time, r], r], (α[time]) /. sol, 
          axis2[time], center[time, r]], 
        ψ[time] /. sol, 
      axis1[time], center[time, r]]}}, 
      Boxed -> False, 
      Lighting -> "Neutral", 
      PlotRange -> {All, All, {-R, 2}}, 
      ViewAngle -> 40 °, 
      ViewPoint -> {1, 0, 2.7}, 
      ImageSize -> {400, 400}]], 
  Style["Animation", Bold],
  {{time, 0.001, ""}, 0.001, tMax, .15, Trigger, 
    AnimationRate -> 1, 
    AppearanceElements -> 
      {"PlayButton", "PauseButton", "StepLeftButton", 
       "StepRightButton", "ResetButton"}, 
    ImageSize -> Large}, 
  Delimiter, 
  Style["Parameters", Bold],
  "\nRadius of the Marble",
  {{r, .1, "r"}, 0.04, 0.3, .01, ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  "Drag on the Marble",
  {{c, .09, "c"}, 0, .15, .01, ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  "Friction between the ball and the surface", 
  {{μ, .07, "μ"}, 0, .25, .01, ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  Delimiter,
  Style["Initial Conditions", Bold],
  "\nAngular Position",
  "  \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(θ\), \(0\)]\)=    π/2",
  {{ϕ0, -2.7, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \(0\)]\)"}, -3.14, 3.14, .01, 
    ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  "\nAngular Speed",
  "  θ\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\('\), \(0\)]\)=0", 
  {{ϕd0, .90, "ϕ\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\('\), \(0\)]\)"}, -2, 2, .01, 
    ImageSize -> Tiny, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  Delimiter,
  {{θ0, π/2}, ControlType -> None},
  {{θd0, 0}, ControlType -> None}, Delimiter, 
  Button["Arbitary Parameters",
    time = 0;
    r = RandomInteger[{0.04, 0.3}];
    c = RandomInteger[{0, 0.15}];
    μ = RandomInteger[{0, 0.25}]],
  {{tMax, 30}, ControlType -> None},
  Row[{"Path Followed", Control[{{tr, True, ""}, {True, False}}]}], 
  {{tMax, 30}, ControlType -> None},
  ControlPlacement -> Left,
  Initialization :> (
    bowl = 
     RegionPlot3D[
       1 < x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1.25, {x, -1.25, 1.25}, {y, -1.25, 
       1.25}, {z, -1.25, 0}, PlotPoints -> 32, 
       BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], 
       Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Mesh -> None, 
       BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .5}, 
       TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2, #3} &)][[1]];
   marble[{x_, y_, z_}, r_] := 
     {{Black, Sphere[{x, y, z}, r]}, {Black, Sphere[{x, y, z + 0.025}, .999 r]}})]
```

[image: demo]

Note this code gives the error message

> NDSolve::depdole: The differential order of a dependent variable in {(α^′)[t],(θ^′)[t],(θ^′′)[t],(ϕ^′)[t],(ϕ^′′)[t],(ψ^′)[t]} exceeds the highest order that appears in the differential equations. >>

so you clearly have some work to do.

Comment: Exactly my comment in the beginning! I believe the differential equations are not formulated properly! {I think your differential equations are not correct. Try to solve them separately, outside the Manipulate first. Since you have four variables, I think you should have four equations and eight initial conditions. Once you successfully solve the DE outside, write a module which takes in time and initial conditions and returns the output of the NDSolve. Modularising the code helps is debugging. } But if the OP has solved, it's solved.

Comment: I am not getting this error when I run it from my side. Will look into it as well.  Is it, possible to rotate the bowl around any particular axis at the same time as the sphere is rolling inside it?

Comment: @Saurav. I totally agree with you.

Comment: @VarunKulkarni. Do you still have `Quiet` in your code. If so, you are living a dream if you think you don't have errors. Using `Quiet` is just a way of denying reality.

Comment: @m_goldberg Is it impolite and detrimental to just abandon once the question is solved? Or is it normal and accepted? Should check in meta though.

Comment: @Saurav. Yes, you should bring the issue up in Meta. It would be better reviewed by the whole community rather discussed just between us two.